# Как создать объект класса в пакете ниже

Tags: java, импорт, package

Изучаю тему пакетов в java. У меня есть основная папка проекта - prog. В ней есть папка src где хранятся пакеты и классы проекта. В папке src я создал класс - NewClass, а также создал там пакет - somePackage. В этом пакете я создал NewSomeClass. В этом классе я создал стартовый метод public static void main. В этом методе я хочу создать объект класса из пакета ниже (NewClass). Но что-то происходит и почему-то программа не видит этого класса. Я забыл его импортировать? Вроде уже перепробовал, но не получалось.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

если именно такая иерархия нужна, то надо файлы местами поменять, чтобы у класса NewSomeClass была возможность сослаться(импортировать) на пакет внутри папки scr.
либо  в пакете somePackage создай новый пакет, туда закинь файлы и там уже тестируй.